# Can anyone help me to understand why `prefix` does not work when `suffix` does and how to fix this?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I think I understand that `prefix` react prop is colliding with html attribute `prefix` here.

What I don't understand is why typescript use html `prefix` when this is a react prop?

Thanks

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-qb0nd?file=/index.tsx

```js
import React, { forwardRef, LegacyRef } from "react";

type Props = React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement> & {
  prefix?: React.ReactNode;
  suffix?: React.ReactNode;
};

const SubMenu: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<unknown, Props> = (
  { prefix, suffix },
  ref
) => {
  const subMenuRef: LegacyRef<HTMLLIElement> =
    (ref as any) || React.createRef<HTMLLIElement>();

  return <li ref={subMenuRef}>hello</li>;
};

const SubMenuEl = forwardRef<unknown, Props>(SubMenu);

export function App() {
  return <SubMenuEl prefix={<div>bb</div>} suffix={<div>aa</div>} />;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using intersection type `&` and it works like that if both of types have the same name of field. You can avoid it like this:

```
type Props = Omit<React.LiHTMLAttributes<HTMLLIElement>, 'prefix'> & {
  prefix?: React.ReactNode;
  suffix?: React.ReactNode;
};
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering questions that don't follow the rules. A question should be self-sustained which, in this case, would require a [mcve] _in the question itself_ and not just a link to an external resource (which is not guaranteed to always show the same content when the question was asked, or will be there as long as this question).